# file get content with json not working

Tags: php, json

`www.youtubeinmp3.com/fetch/?format=JSON&video=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i62Zjga8JOM`

example output :

```
{

  "title":"Happy Forever Alone Day (Forever Alone Song)",
 "length":"125",
 "link":"http:\/\/youtubeinmp3.com\/download\/get\ /?i=k1MakL%2FYlh6KUtEHqyQlg9XwtUUWO"

}
```

i want to get this using php json file get content but this is not working.

```
  <?php 
   $json_url = "www.youtubeinmp3.com/fetch/?format=JSON&video=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i62Zjga8JOM";
$json = file_get_contents($json_url);
$data = json_decode($json, TRUE);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($data);
echo "</pre>";
 ?>
```

but nothing working please help me ..
          $json_url = "www.youtubeinmp3.com/fetch/?format=JSON&video=$videoid";
$videoid is dyanamic value getting using post variable .

likie as

```
  <?php
 $video=$_POST['yturl'];
   echo $video;?>
```

thanks.

Comment: You are missing the scheme part of the URI for one.

Comment: can you please explain this i am new .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using this code to get your output.

```
$curlSession = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_URL, 'www.youtubeinmp3.com/fetch/?format=JSON&video=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i62Zjga8JOM&chof=json');
curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$jsonData = json_decode(curl_exec($curlSession));
curl_close($curlSession);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($jsonData);
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: `foreach($jsonData as $row){
         echo $row->length;
         echo "\n";
     }`  can we print using lopp

Comment: You can get length using $jsonData->length not need to loop.

Comment: one more think i want to pass video id  `www.youtubeinmp3.com/fetch/?format=JSON&video= this part dynamic video id &chof=json`  thispart dynamic video id = post value   `<?php
 $video=$_POST['yturl'];
   echo $video;?>` like using $video  please help me

Comment: Yes you can pass dynamic video id this type 'www.youtubeinmp3.com/fetch/?format=JSON&video=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v='.$v_id.'&chof=json'.

Comment: hello one more thing please how to add php code in this link  `<a href='//www.youtubeinmp3.com/fetch/?video='.$video. please check this' style='text-decoration:none;color:#03a730;'>
<img src='//www.youtubeinmp3.com/icon/download.png' style='vertical-align:middle;'> <strong>Download MP3</strong>
</a>`

Comment: `<a href='//www.youtubeinmp3.com/fetch/?video=' dynamic value  >` check this

Comment: style also mention there

Comment: yes like this <a href='youtubeinmp3.com/fetch/?video='<?php echo $video_id; ?> style='text-decoration:none;color:#03a730;'>

Comment: if this code in your php page then remove <?php ?> tag otherwise its working and perfect running for me.